# Return only object which has regex matched field

Tags: mongodb

My document structure is,

```
{
  "objects" : {
    "obj1": {
      "name" : "AC",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    },
    "obj2": {
      "name" : "BC",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    },
    "obj3": {
      "name" : "AB",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to perform `regex` match on `name` field of all objects inside `objects` and return only the matched sub-objects. I tried the following `match` query,

```
{
  $or: [{
    "object.obj1.name": {
      $regex: "searchText"
    }
  }, {
    "object.obj2.name": {
      $regex: "searchText"
    }
  }, {
    "object.obj3.name": {
      $regex: "searchText"
    }
  }]
}
```

This match works. But what I should have to give in `select` fields? If I give `{"object.obj1": 1, "object.obj2": 1, "object.obj3": 1}`, all sub-objects will be returned if any one `regex` match passes. How can we do `select` conditionally without using aggregation? Is it possible to do without aggregation?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to the answer I want to point out that the schema is not quite right, if you want to nest more than one document use an array instead, this approach will save you a lot of headaches, believe me:

```
{
  "objects" : [
    {
      "name" : "AC",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "BC",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "AB",
      "prop1" : "val1",
      "prop2" : "val2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I guess you want to *filter out* some nested documents that are inside `objects` for each matched document. Sadly, it's a case in which you should use aggregation pipeline. If you didn't know about it, you can filter only one element of the array using projection's operators: [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/), and [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/), but in this case you require to return more than one.

Here's the aggregation pipeline I guess fulfills your requirements:

```
aggregation = [
  {
    // Match documents having at least one nested object with "A" in name
    $match: {
      "objects.name": {
        $regex: "A"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$objects"
  },
  // Match all nested documents containing "A" in name
  {
    $match: {
      "objects.name": {
        $regex: "A"
      }
    }
  },
  // Groups nested documents to return them as individual documents.
  // Here you can add more fields and perform other operations if needed
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$objects.name"
    }
  }
]

db.collection.aggregate(aggregation)
```

I hope this can help you, I don't quite know the output you expect the query to have, but anyways, I may have been able to give you an idea at least! Good luck!